# iOS: UIImagePicker or AVCam for this functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking for a way to add a custom button on camera preview and don't know where to go. Just like the iOS native camera, on the left of the capture button, you can click on it and access photo library. How can we add a button to the camera preview view? Would anyone be kind enough to give some directions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UIImagePickerController's `cameraOverlayView`. This lets you lay your own interface on top of the default camera interface.

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)** sample project. It shows the preview of the camera in a custom `UIView` and uses `AVCaptureSession` for the management of the video preview. You can add whatever you want in the custom `UIView` as you like.